# display select options based on previous selections

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to display drop-down menus 'category'and subcategories. it's been a few years since I used javascript, so I am having some problems. the code I have simply is not populating the html select input. I don't know if the code is too simplistic or if I have just made some small error, but I cant seem to get it work. maybe someone can show me where I'm going wrong. Thanks.

```
<html>
    <select name="cat" id="menu1" class="menu"></select>
    <select name="subcat" id="menu2" class="menu"></select>
</html>

<script type = "text/javascript">

    var data = {
        "category":["sub-category"],
        "music": ["sub-category","rock", "punk"],
        "film": ["sub-categoy","comedy", "drama"],
        "tv": ["sub-catery","sit-com", "soap opera"],
    }


    for (var i in data) {
        $('#menu1').append('<option>' + i + '</option>');
    }


    $('#menu1').change(function() {
        var key = $(this).val();
        $('#menu2').empty();
        for (var i in data[key]) {
            $('#menu2').append('<option>' + data[key][i] + '</option>');
        }
    }).trigger('change');

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've posted jQuery code. E.g.: `$('#menu1')`

So be sure to call the jQuery library in a script tag, and place all such code inside a jQuery block like this:

**UPDATE**

I've fixed the code to make it work. See it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/QYcMt/1/

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    $(function () { 

        var data = {
            "category":["sub-category"],
            "music": ["sub-category","rock", "punk"],
            "film": ["sub-categoy","comedy", "drama"],
            "tv": ["sub-catery","sit-com", "soap opera"],
        };


        $.each(data, function(key, value){            

            $('#menu1').append($('<option />').text(key));
        });


        $('#menu1').change(function() {
            var key = $(this).val();
            $('#menu2').empty();
            for (var i in data[key]) {
                $('#menu2').append('<option>' + data[key][i] + '</option>');
            }
        }).trigger('change');

</script>
```

Comment: thank you that has fixed the problem. I had no idea that you had do that. I appreciate the post :)

Answer (score 0):

The script might be run before the HTML elements are in the DOM? It's always better to wrap your Javascript in

```
$(function() { ...yourcode... });
```

Comment: thanks, I have changed it, it's good to be reminded of these things as I have forgotten alot :)