# display second menu based on first one along with value and id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am referring to another question [display select options based on previous selections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11861884/display-select-options-based-on-previous-selections/49166925?noredirect=1#comment85338957_49166925)

I have while loop to fill the `var data` and inside a foreach loop to give the sub-menu and all work fine, `var data = {'B|1':['B5|1','B4|2']`

now after displaying menu1 How do I display second one, am just stopped there.

my code is:

```
for (var i in data) {
    var ii = i.split('|');
    $('#menu1').append('<option value=' + ii[1] + '>' + ii[0] + '</option>');
}
$('#menu1').change(function () {
    var key = $(this).val();
    $('#menu2').empty();
    for (var i in data[key]) {
        var ii = data[key][i].split('|');
        $('#menu2').append('<option value=' + ii[1] + '>' + ii[0] + '</option>');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

## menu1 is ok, now I need to show #menu2 with the value and text ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```
$('#menu1').change(function() {
    var key = $(this).val();
    var keyText = $('#menu1 :selected').text();
    $('#menu2').empty();
    for (var i in data[keyText +"|" + key]) {
        var ii=data[keyText +"|" + key][i].split('|');
        $('#menu2').append('<option value='+ii[1]+'>' + ii[0] + '</option>');
    }
}).trigger('change');
```

Comment: i tried this portion, not fully understand what u did inside the loop, as for my try it is not working. I can get the value of menu2 from data[i] but still can't apply that inside the <option>

Comment: i have used data array as var data = {'B|1':['B5|1','B4|2'],'C|2':['C2|3','C3|4']}; The key for array is ''B|1'. Selecting value of menu1 will give you only 1 but you need 'B|1' as key. So I concat the selected text with the value to get the key. Please check this fiddle.    
https://jsfiddle.net/q91akr0s/2/